# What is the connection between energy and motion, in a non-trivial sense?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

It seems that without exception and at all scales the presense of Energy walks hand in hand with motion.
It is not without reason to wonder if there is a direct connection between the two,  in a deep sense.
It also seems that energy,  in balance,  threatens motion as a consequence of imbalance , which prompts my curiosity with regard to 
What is the connection between energy and motion,  in a non-trivial sense?

Comment: Energy is the ability to do work. Work is the application of a force over some distance (motion). Is this sufficient for you? I am unsure what you mean by "energy in balance" and "threatening motion" though.

Comment: there are several types of energy. Kinetic energy is directly related to motion and so is thermal energy (in a hot gas, for example) but the energy content of matter is not and neither is chemical potential energy (as in an unexploded stick of dynamite for example). what type of energy are you asking about?

Comment: Static configurations of charges have potential energy but no motion, for example. It's not all motion.

Comment: You're correct, but you won't get a good answer here. Energy is a measure of the speed of the process (that also depends on the speed of time) and everything that exists consists of different processes (e.g. rotations). The energy of a photon is proportional to its frequency and is zero at the black hole horizon where time stops. However, the mass of any object at the horizon is zero. This means that energy is a representation of intrinsic processes that stop when time stops. Mathematically this is expressed by the fact that time and energy are Fourier conjugates (two sides of the same thing).

Comment: Not clear what kind of *deep sense, non-trivial* answer you are looking for, nor what is the *balance v imbalance* threat which you refer to. Your question sounds like a mix of mystical and philosophical, but this is a site for questions about mainstream physics.

Comment: @safesphere That looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @sammygerbil Oh no, answers in comments are not allowed. I hope moderators are not sleeping and will delete this violation promptly. Meanwhile, do you think my comment "*sounds like a mix of mystical and philosophical*" proportional to the question? You see, the dilemma is that people here typically don't understand this kind of questions and their deep relations to physics, so answering them is a guaranteed massive downvote, so why bother? On the other hand, people asking them typically have no idea what they are talking about. Hence they don't understand the answer and never respond. Cheers!

Comment: This is a valid inquiry by an informed user. This site is an asset. Valid facts and informed opinions are what I seek as a user,  and I appreciate that it's what's typically provided by the user..... My question stands.

Comment: With respect to putting this question on hold,  whatever that means,  the question is simple.  What is the known or theorised connection between energy and motion,  in a non-trivial sense?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever your physical system has time-translation symmetry (at the level of your Lagrangian), you have a corresponding conserved quantity according to Noether's theorem - that conserved quantity is energy.

Comment: Your comment is understood,  but does little to strike at the point.